# Returning only specific stats in solr's stats component

Tags: solr

I'm using solr's stats fields to return some information, and while useful, it contains a ton of data I *don't* need.

The query:

```
&stats=true&stats.field=name&stats.calcdistinct=true
```

returns me each distinct/unique value, but by default, it lists out *each* unique value that it finds - which in this case, I don't want - I only want it to return the *number* of results found.  This is fine when the distinct count is under 100 or so, but when if it's 56,000, I am forced to return 56,000 distinct values to the browser, which is expensive:

```
"stats":{
    "stats_fields":{
      "name":{
        "min":"Alan",
        "max":"Zeke",
        "count":197890,
        "missing":0,
        "distinctValues":["Alan",
          "Bob",
          "Matt",
          "Chan",
          "Peter",
          "Zeke"],
        "countDistinct":56872,  // <--- 56,872 lines get returned...
        "facets":{}}}}}
```

Is there a way for me to tell solr I *only want* it to return

`stats --> stats_fields --> name --> countDistinct` and not any other `stats` attribute, like so:

```
"stats":{
        "stats_fields":{
          "name":{
            "countDistinct":56872,  
            }}}}
```

Comment: Could you [use the JSON Facet API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search) with the `unique` facet function?

Comment: I use JSON Facets (which are amazing,) but this particular installation of solr is running an older version that does not have JSON faceting.

Answer (score 0):

Add a local parameter to the query; e.g.:

```
&stats=true&stats.field=name&stats.calcdistinct=true&{!distinctValues=false}name
```

If `stats.calcDistinct` is true, the "countDistinct" and "distinctValues" statistics will be computed and included the response so you need to disable `distinctValues` in order to exclude the list of values from the response.

Comment: Can you provide additional details on how this works, and why this solves the problem?

Comment: Additional details are explained in the official documentation for the Stats Component.

Comment: Oh, yes, I‘m quite confident that‘s true. But, ideally, Stack Overflow seeks to act as a type of „encyclopedia“ of self-contained answers without undue dependency on external resources. At minimum, offering a link to said documentation would be useful. A much better approach would be to add a sentence or two describing what this does and why it solves _this_ problem. Can you do that?